# Detecting a cycle between two vertices in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

I want to make an algorithm that will detect if there exists a path with a cycle between two vertices $(u,v)$ . Now, I know that to detect a cycle in a graph, we check for any back edges. If one exists, we have a cycle. But I need to find if any path between two specific vertices has a cycle. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Use your favorite algorithm to find a path from $u$ to $v$. Mark all of the intermediate vertices along the path as visited and use the same algorithm to find a path from $v$ to $u$. If either of the two passes fail then there is no cycle.

Comment: @JohnDouma why does this cover every possible path? It seems to me like it would cover only two possible paths. What if there exists a path between $v$ to $u$ that wouldn't be discovered because it used a visited node? Also, what if v is a node that does not have any out-edges? Would this still work (sorry, new to graph theory...)

Comment: Since you are using a directed graph you don't need to label the visited vertices. However, to find a cycle you don't need to visit every path. It doesn't matter how you got to $v$. If there is a path from $u$ to $v$ and a path from $v$ to $u$ then there is a cycle. Likewise, if there is a cycle then there is a path from $u$ to $v$ and a path from $v$ to $u$.

Comment: @JohnDouma So, the algorithm consists of using a path-finding algorithm (lets say Djikstra) from $u$ to $v$ in the directed graph. Once that is found, I will try to find another path from $v$ to $u$ using the same algorithm. If there is a path from $v$ to $u$ after finding the path from $u$ to $v$ (and we will save the visited nodes), then there is a cycle. If there isn't, there is no cycle.

Comment: That's how I would do it.

Comment: What exactly does "a path with a cycle between two vertices" mean to you here? Is it a simple cycle that happens to contain both the two vertices of interet? Or a _closed walk_ (i.e. allowed to use vertices and edges more than once) that contains both the two vertices? Or a walk from one vertex to the other that happens to visit at least one node more than once? The suggestion by @JohnDouma will work for the closed-wallk case; the other variants need different approaches,

Comment: @HenningMakholm I want to detect *any* cycle. Whether its simple or otherwise. But I am expecting simple cycles more than anything.

Comment: @JohnLexus: Please clarify what you mean by "detect any cycle". I gave a number of examples to illustrate how that wording can reasonably mean several quite different things -- simply repeating "any cycle" without clarification is not going to help anyone discern what it is you mean.

Comment: @HenningMakholm You're right, I'm sorry, I wrote this while falling asleep. I want to know if any path between vertices $v$ and $u$ contains a cycle. I personally had no idea there were different types of cycles. I am going to assume my program will encounter nothing but simple cycles. So... Simple cycles only. Does that help?

Comment: @JohnLexus: Does that mean that you want to find out whether there _exists_ a walk from $v$ to $u$ (or from $u$ to $v$??) such that there exists a vertex that appears at least twice in that walk?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am sorry, I am a bit new, so bear with me. All I want to know is if there exists a path between $v$ and $u$ that has a simple cycle in it. There can be one path, or two, or three. If any of those have a simple cycle in them, my program should return true. I am sorry if I am repeating myself. I do not know that if a vertex appears at least twice in a traversal that it will mean there is a simple cycle. You sound like the expert here to be honest . I just want to know about a simple cycle. That's it, no bamboozles.

Comment: @JohnLexus: I'm trying to get you to clarify what you mean by "has a simple cycle in it". It appears that you don't agree with my suggestion for what you could mean, but I'm flat out of ideas for what _else_ you could be meaning, and I seem to have no luck in getting you to say anything else than repeats of the description I'm unsure how to interpret.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am not disagreeing with you on your description. I am stating that I really don't know if you are right or wrong and can therefore neither deny nor confirm your statements... Because I am not very learned 

Comment: @JohnLexus: If _you_ don't know what it is you're asking, then I can't help you with finding an answer to a question that, apparently, neither of us knows what is.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think the problem comes from me not understanding what is unclear about this question. You're asking questions that I don't understand. I know exactly what I want. Are you familiar with simple cycles? Are there more than one kind of simple cycles?

Comment: @JohnLexus: I am asking you exactly what you mean by the word "contains" in "contains a simple cycle". My own guess would have been that you mean that there exists a walk from $v$ to $u$ such that there exists at least one vertex that appears more than once in the walk, but you have been unwilling to confirm that is what you mean, and you have been similarly unwilling to given any _other_ explanation of what you mean, other than repeating "contains a simple cycle" again and again, as if repeating it once more would suddenly make it make sense to me

Comment: My next question would have been to get you to clarify what you mean by "between $v$ and $u$" -- in particular whether you're talking about a path that starts at $v$ and ends at $u$, or a walk that _either_ starts at $v$ and ends at $u$ _or_ starts at $u$ and ends at $v$ -- or something third entirely. But by now I'm not optimistic that I would get you to commit to one of those possibilities, _or_ provide any alternative description of what it is you mean,

Comment: So I can't help you. Goodbye and good luck.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Aha! I understand. Maybe I was phrasing it wrong? Yes, you are right

Comment: @HenningMakholm By a path between $v$ and $u$, I meant a walk starting at $v$ (so v is the source) and ending at $u$ (so u is the target).